# Find the Interval of convergence, help?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Find the convergence interval of the series:

well it goes to infinity and $n=0$ of $n^3(5x+10)^n$  :)

EDIT: I solved it, I had to use the ratio test and endt up with 5x+10<1 and then just solved the equation and checked endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the n-th root test is used here and note that (n^3)^(1/n) = (n^(1/n))^3 ---> 1^3 = 1 as n---> infinity. You need to show that n^(1/n) --> 1.

Comment: why do I need to show that  n^(1/n) --> 1.? and where do you get  (n^3)^(1/n) from?